# How to incorporate Standand Error code in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe in R, I achieve a bar plot by this code.

```
Dataset<- c("MO", "IP", "MP","CC")
GPP <- c(1, 3, 4,3)
NPP<-c(4,3,5,2)
df <- data.frame(Dataset,GPP,NPP)
df.m<-melt(df)
ggplot(df.m, aes(Dataset, value, fill = variable)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")
```

I calculate the standard error by:

```
my_se <- df.m %>%
  group_by(Dataset) %>%
  summarise(n=n(),
            sd=sd(value),
            se=sd/sqrt(n))
```

How can I incorporate the Standard Error code to my ggplot code?
I tried this:

```
df.m %>% 
  left_join(my_se) %>% 
  ggplot(df.m, aes(Dataset, value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=Dataset, ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se)+
  scale_fill_manual(labels = c("GPP", "NPP"),values=cbp1)
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done 2-3 mistakes like mentioning `df.m` within `ggplot` function, in `ymin` and `ymax` within `geom_errorbar` you have mentioned `mean` which should be `value`. In `scale_fill_manual` you have provided `values=cbp1` but your code does not have anything related `cbp1`. So, use the following corrected code

```
library(tidyverse)

Dataset<- c("MO", "IP", "MP","CC")
GPP <- c(1, 3, 4,3)
NPP<-c(4,3,5,2)
df <- data.frame(Dataset,GPP,NPP)
df.m<-reshape2::melt(df)

ggplot(df.m, aes(Dataset, value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")

my_se <- df.m %>%
  group_by(Dataset) %>%
  summarise(n=n(),
            sd=sd(value),
            se=sd/sqrt(n))

df.m %>% 
  left_join(my_se) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Dataset, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=Dataset, ymin=value-se, ymax=value+se), width=0.4, position = position_dodge(.9))
```

[image]